# How to get python to deal with very small numbers?

Tags: python, traveling-salesman, simulated-annealing

I am doing a simulated annealing analysis of a travelling salesmen problem, I keep running in to the error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I am not dividing by 0, but I am dividing by a value very close to it, but I do not want python to assume that it is 0, I want it to actually perform the calculation, even it it takes a long time.

Here is a snippet of my code where the error is occurring, `temperature` is the value which is getting very close to 0.

```
def probability(d_new, d_old, temperature):
    delta = d_new - d_old
    if d_new - d_old >= 0:
        probability = (math.e) ** - (delta/temperature)
    else:
        probability = 1
    return probability
```

I am using Jupyter Notebooks to run Python, but I am not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: I don't think ZeroDivisionError triggers on anything except zero. E.g. I can divide by 5e-324, the smallest possible float, and that doesn't trigger it. Are you sure that you don't have a variable which is zero? Can you reproduce the problem by calling `probability()` with a fixed, non-zero value?

Comment: Just fyi if you know you need very tight decimal precision there's also https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Do you understand the limitations of floating point numbers?  These are implemented in hardware, so your "takes a long time" comment is not relevant.  Either the number fits in a double-precision floating point, or it does not.  If it does not fit, it is 0.  And, by the way, if you divide by a very small number, the result is going to be a very large number, unless delta is much less than one.

Comment: If your denominator is something like `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, you'll always get ZeroDivisionError even if you use decimal module

Comment: @journpy That is simply not true: https://ideone.com/9qnZSS

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: More crucially, the code you posted _obviously_ leads to a division by zero error if `temperature` is zero. What we need for a [mre] is code which actual reproduces the reported problem with a value which isn't zero. Please also review the rest of the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @blhsing you are absolutely right. I forgot to add my quotation marks in the denominator. So I used without the quotes `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent errors, you need to include both temperature and delta in the if statement.

```
def probability(d_new, d_old, temperature):
delta = d_new - d_old
if d_new - d_old >= 0 and temperature > 0:
    probability = (math.e) ** - (delta/temperature)
else:
    probability = 1
return probability
```